# почему некорректно обновляется элемент?

Tags: reactjs

[image: результат]
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ClockTimer extends Component{

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentTime: new Date().toLocaleString() };
}; 
componentDidMount(){
this.changeTime();
}

componentDidUpdate()
{
    console.log("componentDidUpdate");
}
changeTime()
{
    this.interv = setInterval(()=>{
        this.setState({currentTime : new Date().toLocaleString()});
    }),1000
}



render(){
    return (<div>{this.state.currentTime}</div>)
}
```

}

export default ClockTimer;

Answer (score 0):

Фрагмент `,1000` нужно внести в скобку, чтобы получилось так

```
changeTime()
{
    this.interv = setInterval(()=>{
        this.setState({currentTime : new Date().toLocaleString()});
    },1000)
}
```

Comment: спасибо, мне стыдно ((